# How to fix text being misplaced in .SVG image but showing in the correct place in .PNG?

Tags: c#, .net, svg, png, drawing

I'm using `SVGNet` to draw `SVG` images and save them in both `.svg` and `.png` formats. However, when I add text and rotate it, the `.png` file shows the image correctly but the `.svg` file doesn't.

I'm exploring `SvgNet`, hardcoding the kind of drawings I'll have to dynamically produce.
However, I can't seem to solve this problem. I've tried different rotations and adding translations, but to no avail. 
If I don't add any transformations it doesn't even add the spacing, the text elements show up on top of each other.

Here's all the code, except the saving to `.svg` and `.png`.

```
SvgDocument x = new SvgDocument();
x.Width = 2500;
x.Height = 2500;

List<string> exemplosParagem = new List<string>
{
    "Paragem 1",
    "Paragem 2",
    "Paragem 3",
    "Paragem 4",
    "Paragem 5",
    "Paragem 6",
    "Paragem 7",
    "Paragem 8",
    "Paragem 9",
    "Paragem 10",
    "O Que Acontece",
    "Se o Texto for de",
    "Tamanhos",
    "Diferentes"
};

SvgUnitCollection textPositionX = new SvgUnitCollection
{
    1250
};

SvgUnitCollection textPositionY = new SvgUnitCollection
{
    100
};

SvgGroup title = new SvgGroup();
title.Children.Add(new SvgText
{
    Text = "Teste Espinha SVG Library",
    FontSize = 80,
    Fill = new SvgColourServer(Color.Blue),
    Stroke = new SvgColourServer(Color.Black),
    StrokeWidth = 3,
    TextAnchor = SvgTextAnchor.Middle,
    X = textPositionX,
    Y = textPositionY
});


SvgGroup spineLine = new SvgGroup();
spineLine.Children.Add(new SvgLine
{
    StrokeWidth = 10,
    Stroke = new SvgColourServer(Color.Black),
    StartX = 100,
    StartY = 600,
    EndX = 2300,
    EndY = 600,
});


SvgGroup rect = new SvgGroup();
rect.Children.Add(new SvgRectangle
{
    Fill = new SvgColourServer(Color.LightBlue),
    Stroke = new SvgColourServer(Color.Black),
    StrokeWidth = 2,
    Width = x.Width - 50,
    Height = x.Height - spineLine.Bounds.Bottom - 100,
    X = 25,
    Y = spineLine.Bounds.Bottom + 100,
});

SvgUnitCollection paragensPositionX = new SvgUnitCollection
{
    spineLine.Bounds.X
};

SvgUnitCollection paragensPositionY = new SvgUnitCollection
{
   spineLine.Bounds.Top
};

List<SvgText> svgText = new List<SvgText>();

for (int i = 0; i < exemplosParagem.Count; i++)
{
    SvgText aux = new SvgText
    {
        Text = exemplosParagem[i],
        Color = new SvgColourServer(Color.Black),
        FontSize = 20,
        X = paragensPositionX,
        Y = paragensPositionY
    };

    SvgTransformCollection transCollect = new SvgTransformCollection();
    SvgRotate rotation = new SvgRotate(-35, aux.Bounds.X, aux.Bounds.Y);
    transCollect.Add(rotation);

    aux.Transforms = transCollect;

    paragensPositionX[0] += (spineLine.Bounds.Width / exemplosParagem.Count);

    svgText.Add(aux);
}


foreach (var stop in svgText)
{
    spineLine.Children.Add(stop);
}

x.Children.Add(title);
x.Children.Add(spineLine);
x.Children.Add(rect);

var bitmap = x.Draw();
```

The following are the images generated by this code in `.png` and `.svg` respectively. The `PNG` image is the correct one.

[image: PNG Image]
[image: Print of the SVG Image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I had to create `paragensPositionX` inside the loop.

```
SvgUnitCollection paragensPositionX = new SvgUnitCollection();
if (i == 0)
{
    paragensPositionX.Add(spineLine.Bounds.X);
}
else
{
    paragensPositionX.Add(auxSpacing + spacing);
}
```